# Ramda - how to get multiple properties from array

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to get two properties from an array of objects which looks like this:

```
const nodes = [
 {
    "id": "0",
    "outgoingNodeIds": ['1', '2'],
    "outgoingVirtualNodes": [
        {
            "virtualNodeId": "5",
        },
        {
            "virtualNodeId": "10",
        }
    ],
 }
]
```

I need to get `outgoingNodeIds` which is a simple array of strings and `outgoingVirtualNodes` which is an array of objects and I need to get `virtualNodeId` from it.

There is no problem with getting only one property at the time and then concat two arrays ([example in ramda](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.28.0#?const%20nodes%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22outgoingNodeIds%22%3A%20%5B%271%27%2C%20%272%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22outgoingVirtualNodes%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22virtualNodeId%22%3A%20%225%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22virtualNodeId%22%3A%20%2210%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20prop1%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.pluck%28%27outgoingNodeIds%27%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.flatten%0A%29%28nodes%29%0A%0Aconst%20prop2%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.pluck%28%27outgoingVirtualNodes%27%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.map%28R.pluck%28%27virtualNodeId%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.flatten%0A%29%28nodes%29%0A%0A%0AR.concat%28prop1%2C%20prop2%29%0A%0A)):

```
const prop1 = R.pipe(
    R.pluck('outgoingNodeIds'),
    R.flatten
)(nodes)

const prop2 = R.pipe(
    R.pluck('outgoingVirtualNodes'),
    R.map(R.pluck('virtualNodeId')),
    R.flatten
)(nodes)

R.concat(prop1, prop2)
```

But I would like to combine this into one pipe if possible. I know how to get two properties at once but I don't know how to map the second one to get `virtualNodeId`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *R.ap* to apply a list of functions to the array - each function produces a new array of values from all object objects in the original array, and then flatten to a single array. The end result would be an array of all `outgoingNodeIds` from all objects, and then the `virtualNodeId` from all objects:

```js
const { pipe, ap, prop, pluck, flatten } = R

const fn = pipe(
  ap([
    prop('outgoingNodeIds'),
    pipe(prop('outgoingVirtualNodes'), pluck('virtualNodeId'))
  ]),
  flatten,
)

// Note that are two objects - a and b
const nodes = [{"id":"0","outgoingNodeIds":["1a","2a"],"outgoingVirtualNodes":[{"virtualNodeId":"5a"},{"virtualNodeId":"10a"}]},{"id":"1","outgoingNodeIds":["3b","4b"],"outgoingVirtualNodes":[{"virtualNodeId":"15b"},{"virtualNodeId":"20b"}]}]

const result = fn(nodes)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

If you want the `outgoingNodeIds` and then `virtualNodeId` of each object together replace *R.ap* with *R.map* and *R.juxt*. The *R.juxt* apply a list of functions to a list of parameters (a single object in this case).

```js
const { pipe, map, juxt, prop, pluck, flatten } = R

const fn = pipe(
  map(juxt([
    prop('outgoingNodeIds'),
    pipe(prop('outgoingVirtualNodes'), pluck('virtualNodeId'))
  ])),
  flatten,
)

// Note that are two objects - a and b
const nodes = [{"id":"0","outgoingNodeIds":["1a","2a"],"outgoingVirtualNodes":[{"virtualNodeId":"5a"},{"virtualNodeId":"10a"}]},{"id":"1","outgoingNodeIds":["3b","4b"],"outgoingVirtualNodes":[{"virtualNodeId":"15b"},{"virtualNodeId":"20b"}]}]

const result = fn(nodes)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Since we're dealing with a single object on each iteration of *R.map*, you can replace *R.juxt* with *R.applySpec*:

```js
const { pipe, map, applySpec, prop, pluck, flatten } = R

const fn = pipe(
  map(applySpec([
    prop('outgoingNodeIds'),
    pipe(prop('outgoingVirtualNodes'), pluck('virtualNodeId'))
  ])),
  flatten,
)

// Note that are two objects - a and b
const nodes = [{"id":"0","outgoingNodeIds":["1a","2a"],"outgoingVirtualNodes":[{"virtualNodeId":"5a"},{"virtualNodeId":"10a"}]},{"id":"1","outgoingNodeIds":["3b","4b"],"outgoingVirtualNodes":[{"virtualNodeId":"15b"},{"virtualNodeId":"20b"}]}]

const result = fn(nodes)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Even years after first seeing it, I'm amazed by this usage of `applySpec`!  It wasn't intended for arrays, but simply works perfectly!

Comment: Well *juxt* actually links to *applySpec* :)

Comment: Sure, but most of those links are for related functions, not something that can do the whole job of the function, even in limited circumstances.  The point was simply that we only ever intended for `applySpec` to work with objects, until someone pointed out that it works equally well with arrays.  It's always fun to find out your implementation is more general than you knew!

Answer (score 2):

Ori Drori has already given several great Ramda versions.  But let's not forget how simple this can be in modern JS:

```js
const extractNodeIds = (nodes) => nodes .flatMap ((node) => [
  ... (node .outgoingNodeIds),
  ... (node .outgoingVirtualNodes .map (vn => vn .virtualNodeId))
])

const nodes = [{id: '0', outgoingNodeIds: ['1', '2'], outgoingVirtualNodes: [{virtualNodeId: '5'}, {virtualNodeId: '10'}]}]

console .log (extractNodeIds (nodes))
```

Ramda was designed and mostly built in the days before ES6 was ubiquitous.  But these days, tools like `flatMap` and the array `...spread` syntax make many problems that Ramda solved so nicely almost as nice in plain JS.  It's not that I don't love the tool -- I'm a Ramda founder and a big fan -- but it no longer seems as necessary as it once did.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I get your point and will think about that next time.